# Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir (Errno::EACCES) - on application run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, permissions

I have a ruby web app configured, with all the gems installed etc. It runs fine through my apache server, but now I have to debug something (which I'm still figuring out) and I need to run the `rails server -b (ip) -p (port)` command.
However I get the following outcome:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.12 application starting in development on http://192.168.39.163:3004
=> Run 'rails server -h' for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in 'mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/vicky/vanerum/tmp/pids (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in 'fu_mkdir'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `reverse_each'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `each'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `mkdir_p'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:71:in `block in start'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /home/vicky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I've changed ~/.rbenv's owner to myself, I've tried setting the permissions to 775 on that folder. It keeps giving me this error. Any more ideas?

Comment: Do you have the folder `tmp` in the `/home/vicky/vanerum/` ?

Comment: No... I'll make one. See if that fixes things

Comment: Omg that was it! Can't believe I read straight accross that line. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder in `/home/vicky/vanerum/` with name `tmp`.

<sub>For a case, create a folder `pids` in `/home/vicky/vanerum/tmp`.

I assume the problem in `thin` server, it not able  to create folder.</sub>